# How to solve Deployment Error in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have just updated Visual Studio 2017 and create one new project. It build successfully but giving deployment error. Application doesn't deploy on my Samsung J7 device. Before the update, it was working fine.

How to resolve this?

[image: Error]

Comment: check this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/62307/xamarin-android-projects-failed-to-deploy-in-visual-studio-emulator-for-android

Comment: [Here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/209865/cannot-deploy-xamarin-forms-app-error-install-pars.html), the same issue.

Comment: Hi, on  15.6.1, have you tried reinstall the Android SDK?

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT, No I haven't. Because I have already downgrade VS2017

Comment: Yes, I hope you can try it, this morning, I think it maybe the SDK's problem, so I reinstall it, and work. Can you help me to verify it?

Comment: Sorry, Now I don't want to update VS with latest version at this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are four solutions:

-[read this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/211740/apk-signature-fails-apksignerbat.html)

-This bug is in last version Visual Studio 15.6. If you use this version make downgrade to 15.5.

1. [How delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017) current version
2. Download older version - select your version on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017).

-Or wait for the next update

-or disable the signing of the apk in the properties of your project.
Edit your csproj and set :

```
<AndroidKeyStore>false</AndroidKeyStore>
```

But in this case you will not be able to publish your package in Google Play.

Comment: Where can I find this? "<AndroidKeyStore>false</AndroidKeyStore>"

Comment: I have edit csproj in notpad++ but I can not find <AndroidKeyStore> this tag

Comment: In Visual Studio right-click on your  android project: unload, and edit.

Comment: I have to add this tag?

Comment: Try add this tag in your csproj:parent tag PropertyGroup(for debug configuration) . This is not a very beautiful solution but faster than reinstallation.

Comment: Still getting same error. I think I might be added code wrong place.

Comment: Me too, I also try add it into both `Debug|AnyCPU` and  `Debug`.

Comment: @FetFrumos, can you please tell me how to make downgrade to 15.5? I  can't find it.

Comment: @FetFrumos, yes, please tell us how to downgrade version of VS2017?

Comment: @FetFrumos, Thank you

Comment: I added link to download

Comment: @FetFrumos, Yes, Old version works as expected. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

download the used SDK. Update your visual Studio(if u r not using the latest one). Check Paths. Restart Visual Studio after that. it will run

Comment: Check if there is any UI issue present or not. Sometimes due to some hidden issues it wont run.

Answer (score 0):

About 15.6.1, I suggest you uninstall all of your Android SDK, and reinstall, it works for me!

Also you can refer to [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/209865/cannot-deploy-xamarin-forms-app-error-install-pars.html?childToView=215698#comment-215698).