# Xamarin Deploy Issue - "apksigner.BAT" exited with code 1

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I've already googled it, seems some people are complaining the Visual Studio 15.6 version that this trouber has begun.

-I've already tried uninstall Java 9 and back to Java 1.8.0_161 with no success
-I've already tried changing last line of "apksigner.bat" to:
call "%java_exe%" %javaOpts% -classpath "%frameworkdir%" -jar "%jarpath%" %params%
-Tried enable ProGuard

No success...

Does anyone is facing this problem? Anyone has a solution?
Or Microsoft messed things up in this update?

Comment: What is the version about your VS?

Comment: No, not yet. I'm using version 15.6.6. I'm afraid of needing reinstall all. I've read people just solved after reinstall Windows.

Comment: Yes, have a try! Everything will be ok!

Comment: I reinstalled eveything but now the error has changed from "exited with code 1" to "exited with code 2" :'(

Comment: [MultiDexApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004161/java-exe-exited-with-code-2-xamarin-android-project)?

Comment: I've enabled these options but the error still persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same problem when I updated my VS to 15.6.1. I remember that I have spend about 1.5 day to make my VS work. Finally, I made it by reinstalling the Android SDK, you can look [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/209865/cannot-deploy-xamarin-forms-app-error-install-pars.html?childToView=215698#comment-215698).

Also, you can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49234509/how-to-solve-deployment-error-in-xamarin-forms/49247807#49247807), like @FetFrumos said, you can downgrade to 15.5.

But now I am using the 15.6.4, so you can update your VS to the last version.

If @FetFrumos's answer can't help you, you can reinstall the VS.

Comment: I had to reinstall all Visual Studio and stopped using a "global" SDK (shared in C:\ between Android Studio e VS) and used the default SDK  provided by Microsoft installed in default location. So far, no problems anymore

Answer (score 0):

VS 15.6.6 / java 1.8.0_162
Originally failing to find keystore even though both were present.
Did a Repair
Now get apksigner.bat exited with code 1